# Set OpenVPN to turn off TAP Adapter when it loses connection

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, openvpn, hotspot, credentials

Here is my current setup:
I'm connected to a Wi-Fi hotspot that closes the connection every 1h 30min. After that, credentials are asked to resume the connection. To do this, I'm using a Java application that checks for the timeout and automatically logs me back again.

As soon as I start the OpenVPN client, the Java application that monitors the hotspot status switches to the TAP adapter. When the hotspot kicks me out, the app doesn't switch back to the regular Wi-Fi adapter and therefore, cannot log me back in.

Is there any particular OpenVPN config that I can use to disable the TAP adapter while OpenVPN tries to reconnect to its server?

I have already tried with ForceBindIP (under Windows 7) to force the Java app to use the wireless network card, but it doesn't seem to work that well with javaw and jar files.
I would greatly appreciate any help!

**edit 1:**
OpenVPN client conf file:

```
client
remote <vpn server address> 443
dev tun
proto tcp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-auth ta.key 1
ca ca.crt
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
link-mtu 1560
comp-lzo
auth-user-pass pass.txt
```

With this configuration, the vpn works fine.

Comment: Please post your OpenVPN client config.

Comment: I have added the client config minus the server address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in this case, the culprit is the `persist-tun` option.

Excerpt from [OpenVPN man page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html):

> - `--persist-tun`
>
>   Don't close and reopen TUN/TAP device or run up/down scripts across SIGUSR1 or `--ping-restart` restarts.
>
>   SIGUSR1 is a restart signal similar to SIGHUP, but which offers finer-grained control over reset options.

Comment: Testing it right now, looks like it could work! Thanks ! **edit:** It works perfectly fine.